# When you mark an entity as deleted it marks its children as well, is there a way to only mark the parent deleted?

Tags: breeze

When you mark an entity as deleted by setting the entityAspect it marks its children as deleted as well.  Is there a way to only mark the parent deleted? Or a way to go through and mark the children as unchanged after the fact?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to mess with the navigation properties - I will tell you that straight away.  My suggestion is to model your question as if you had to ask it using T-SQL.

In T-SQL, can you delete a parent record, but leave the children?  No.  I mean you could, but why?  You just created orphaned child records in the database.  Are you going to delete the foreign key but leave the data?  What a mess.

The only reason you are able to map a parent child relationship in Breeze is because of the navigation properties that were created based on the parent / child relationships defined in the database.  If you can't do it in the database, you can't do it in Breeze.

If the model refuses to budge and you decide to go forward with this anyway, you need to return data that is not linked via relationships.  You can create a view for the parent and children... but you will need to manually manage the load.  If your entities are based on a view, they probably are not going to be updatable.

Sorry, no code to post.  I gave up on this a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Breeze does not mark child entities as deleted if you delete the parent. We haven't implemented cascading deletes in Breeze. You must have code in your application that is doing this. Breeze disconnects the child entities from the deleted parent by clearing the foreign key properties, so the child entities will be in modified state. However, you won't be able to successfully save w/o violating FK constraints in your DB. You either have to implement cascading deletes on the server or manually delete the child entities.